# React Native: How to support an external iPad keyboard (UIKeyCommand)?

Tags: react-native, ipad, react-native-ios, uikeycommand

The iPad works with external bluetooth keyboards, and the iPad Pro has a Smart Keyboard, which you can support natively using the [UIKeyCommand](https://nshipster.com/uikeycommand/) API.

How can I use these keyboard shortcuts **in React Native**?

[image: screenshot of keyboard shortcuts, from NSHipster's site]

Comment: Did you find an answer 1 1/2 years later?

Comment: Kinda-sorta! We're about to ship it in the Khan Academy app in our next release; I intend to do a write-up about it. (In case I don't get around to writing it up: our native iOS code exposes & accepts the shortcuts with iOS, and then passes those commands to our RN code where the actions are handled.)

Comment: Awesome! I had thought the API would have to be handled in the native code first and then passed back. This could be a good open source package. Looking forward to the write-up :)